# How to get avarge rating of the paired data in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I a some paired dataset like below (table):

| ID1 | ID2 | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |

I want to use sqlite3 query to extract the average paired rating for each ID. The output should be:

```
Item 1: average(2,4);
Item 2: average(2,3,1);
Item 4: average(4,3);
Item 5: average(1);
```

However, the only way I can think about is:

```
SELECT id1, AVG(rating)
FROM table
GROUP BY id1;
```

This will only give me the average rating of:

```
Item 1: average(2,4);
Item 2: average(3,1)
```

May I ask how can I get my desired output by modifying the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` with a `cte`:

```
with cte(id, rating) as (
   select id1, rating from ratings
   union all
   select id2, rating from ratings
)
select id, ave(rating) from cte group by id;
```